# Angular - making a https api call with ssl and keypairs

Tags: angular, api, ssl, https, openssl

I currently using http but now I need to shift to https. I have configured back-end with https and ssl (Java Spring). So the problem is that I have searched I fined lack of info on how to configure angular(client-side) to work with keypairs and ssl in order to call https APi`s. So maybe somebody have had a similar issue and could explain how to make a API request with ssl and keypair, how to open jks files in angular, how to attach them to header (or body) ???

PS. Also probably for this reason is better to write a interceptor ?

Comment: Why do you think that you need "keypairs" to call an API?

Comment: I probably have lack of understanding. In my understanding, in order to establish secure connection between the front-end (single site app) and back-end you need to set up keystores (with a cert) in both sides and share the public keys. At the back and what i did is create a selfsigne.jks file which contains all the pulic keys of client side (still in testing). So when the client request an api call it is allowed (checked via 'soupui' and it worked).  But npw I whant to test the api call via angular, but I dont know how to I import the jks file how do I config the api call to encrypt the info?

Comment: Have you ever added "keypairs" in your browser while using HTTPS, eg. for banking or online shopping? If you are running AJAX calls, your browser handles all that SSL stuff under the hood, so why don't you just try all that out and see what happens?